# Is it safe to use "yes","no","i","out" as name for variables/enum?

Tags: c++, variables, enums, naming-conventions

I have read the document about naming rule of C++, they seems to be usable names.

However, in practice, when I tried to create a variable/enum with a name like   `iter`, `yes`, `no`, `out`, `i`, `Error`, etc. , Visual Studio will strangely use *italic* font for them.

[image]

I can only guess that they are reserved for special thing, and IDE (e.g. refactoring/rename process) might act strangely if I use such names.

Is it safe to use  those names in practice?   Am I just too panic?

Sorry if it is too newbie or an inappropriate question.
I doubt about it for a few weeks but too afraid to ask.

Comment: Those names are legal for you to use. `iter` and `i` are commonly used when just limiting to the scope of a `for` loop. Bear in mind that they are not particularly *good* names, as they carry no meaning, and don't help you understand the code.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you!  Do you happen to also know about "yes","no"?  I should not use them?  If it always be this ways, I will assume that the italic-name is bad practice and I will treat it like a compiler warning.

Comment: @cppBeginner - It's highly subjective. In one scope, those names may carry all the meaning you need to understand their use. In another they may be woefully inadequate. There's no objective answer we can give.

Comment: @cppBeginner What would you assume the intention is if a variable's name is "yes"? That could be *anything*. `i` within a for loop is quite self-explaining because of being common practice (you want to **i**terate...), otherwise, it doesn't tell you much. You should always chose names that clearly indicate the purpose of the variable (`bool isConnected; unsigned int numberOfClients; double tolerance;` - the latter one e. g. in context of some mathematical calculations).

Comment: @StoryTeller  I feel that the things which can break code are 1.global variable  2.macro ..... Is it what you mean?   If so, are there anything else?

Comment: @Aconcagua  Today I have an urge to code `enum class AttributeRenderUpdate{ Yes, No, Special };`.  I panic when I saw *`Yes`* as italic.  (I panic easily because I am c++ beginner.)

Comment: @cppBeginner - No. The things you mentioned are covered by variable shadowing and namespaces (also macros are best avoided). What I meant is how big the piece of code where the variable is used? Do I need to jump around to the top, just to be reminded of what purpose the variable serves? That's a criteria for a good or bad name.

Comment: @cppBeginner In this case: As you used `enum class A` and not just `enum A`, you use yes/no/special always in context with the enum: `AttributeRenderUpdate::Yes`. So it is quite clear in this case what the meaning is, so it is fine.

Comment: @cppBeginner But these are enum identifiers, not variable names...

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank, I understand it now.   (In my case, I intend to use it only within <= 2 classes)

Comment: @Aconcagua   I am so glad.  Now, I can use it in my enums.  Thank.  XD

Comment: @cppBeginner The important point is: Whatever name you choose for an identifier, be it a variable, an enum member, class, function, ... - the name should give a clear hint to what the specific item serves for or does. Sure, you'll often have to find a compromise between good explanation and brevity (function name with 200 characters won't help you any more either...). You could do a little test for yourself: Show some code snippets to a mate of yours and let him explain what she thinks the item's purpose is. The closer he gets to your own intention, the better the name is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These names are valid and will not cause any "harm", the standard only says:

> - Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the
>     implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Which means that all your names are fine to use in user-code. Visual Studio might just have a thing for these names as `i` and `iter` are usually used in looping.

Comment: Do you mean they are Visual Studio-specific symptom?  Thank

Comment: @cppBeginner Yes.

Answer (score 1):

These names are not reserved in standard C++, as explained by Rick Astley. An implementation may choose to accept additional reserved words to provide language *extensions*, such as `ref class` in C++/CLI. In some cases, such as with `ref class`, where `ref` is a *contextual keyword*, these extensions only make otherwise ill-formed programs well-formed in the scope of the extended language. In other cases, an otherwise well-formed program may change its meaning or become ill-formed. In the former case, the implementation is still conforming to the C++ standard, as long as it issues all mandatory diagnostics; in the latter case, it is certainly not conforming.

It is considered good practice to make the latter kind of extensions *optional* e.g. using a command line option, so that the implementation still has a mode in which it is fully standards compliant. My immediate guess is that VC++ in fact does allow you to write well-formed programs containing `yes`, `no`, `i`, `iter` which will behave as required by the standard (implementation bugs notwithstanding).

The IDE is a different beast, though. It is considered to be outside of the scope of the C++ standard, and might discourage or even stop you from writing perfectly well-formed code. That would still be a quality of implementation issue, or an issue of customer satisfaction, if you will.